# how set value of Row datagrid to the header of another datagrid?

Tags: wpf

I want to change header of datagrid1 when changing the Rows below column of datagrid2 .

it's the code of  DataGrid2 column that generates Automaticaly.
How can I bind  Rows of c1 column to the headers of datagrid 1?

```
 public class DataGridStructure
    {

        public string NameField { get; set; }
        public string HeaderText { get; set; }

    }
    public List<DataGridStructure> CreateDataTable()
    {

        List<DataGridStructure> dgs = new List<DataGridStructure>();
        dgs.Add(new DataGridStructure() { NameField ="name field1" , HeaderText = "Header1" });
        dgs.Add(new DataGridStructure() { NameField = "name field2", HeaderText = "Header2" });
        dgs.Add(new DataGridStructure() { NameField = "name field3", HeaderText = "Header3" });
        dgs.Add(new DataGridStructure() { NameField = "name field4", HeaderText = "Header4" });  
         return dgs;

     }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        c1.Header = "name Field";
        c1.Binding = new Binding("NameField");
        dataGrid2.Columns.Add(c1);

            DataGridTextColumn c2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
        c2.Header = ""Header Text;
        c2.Binding = new Binding("HeaderText");
        c2.IsReadOnly = true;
        dataGrid2.Columns.Add(c2);
 dataGrid2.ItemsSource = CreateDataTable();
    }
```

its design code of datagrid1 that Bind to the DataBase:

```
<DataGrid

                                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                          RowHeaderWidth="30" Name="datagrid1"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                          FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                                          LoadingRow="DataGrid_LoadingRow"
                                          IsReadOnly="True" >
                                       <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn  Width="100"  Binding="{Binding Path=Turn}"   FontSize="14" FontWeight="bold" />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn  Width="100"  Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"   FontSize="14" FontWeight="bold" />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn   Width="100"  Binding="{Binding Path=Date}"   FontSize="14" FontWeight="bold"/>                                              
                                            <DataGridTextColumn  Width="100"  Binding="{Binding Path=Amount}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="bold" />                    
                                       </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
```

if more information needed please tell me, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean "How can I bind **cells text** of c1 column to the headers of datagrid1"? If you assing `dataGrid2.ItemsSource` from code, and you know that datagrid1 has 4 headers (because you statically define them in xaml) - why don't you want to just assign text to that 4 headers from code from the same `button1_Click` handler?

Comment: @Sam because I want the user itself changes the headers text of datagrid1 through rows of controling datagrid i.e datagrid2. yes U are true, I want Bind cells of c1 column to the headers DG1, please tell me how I can Bind? tnx